# Creating a hashmap from excel file of type <String, HashMap> in java

Tags: java

Hi I am creating a HashMap from excel file having values as

[image]

So, Result should be of `{D1={C1=V1, C2=V2, C3=3},V D2={C4=V1, C5=V2}}` format.

Here, is the code:

```
HashMap<String,HashMap> list = new HashMap<String,HashMap>();
HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashSet<String> dst = new HashSet<String>();

for(int rowIndex = DATA_ROW; rowIndex <= numRows; rowIndex++) {
    Row row = getRow();
    String loc = getLocation();
    String code = getCode();
    result.put(code, loc);

    String d = getDestinationValue();
    dst.add(d);

    list.put(d, result);
}
return list;
```

Problem, which I face is the result list is cant be cleared as, it also clears the previous values and result achieved by this is wrong as:

```
{D1={C1=V1, C2=V2, C3=3, C4=V1, C5=V2},V D2={C1=V1, C2=V2, C3=3, C4=V1, C5=V2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the variable `result` to represent all results. You should be getting it from the final map each time.

For example, if you result is defined as

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new HashMap<>();
```

Then for each row you would do

```
result.putIfAbsent(destination, new HashMap<>())
result.get(destination).put(code, value);
```

Note that `putIfAbsent` is Java 8. If you are using a previous version then use `containsKey` and `put` to achieve the equivalen.

Comment: thanks aton. yes this work. if(!list.containsKey(dst)) {
    finalList.put(dst, new HashMap<String, String>());
   } 
   finalList.get(dst).put(code, val);

Comment: @user2184688 That's great. Please accept the answer if it works for you.